# Number of Vibrations for Notifications

Tags: notifications, 9.0-pie, vibration

My phone just updated to Android Pie, and like many hapless users I'm trying to adapt to the many changes. One thing that annoys me to no end, and that I can't seem to find any information on, is that the number of vibrations for a notification has jumped from two to five. I like having vibrations turned on for notifications, especially if I'm in a meeting or at a loud event, but if I'm getting five vibrations I'm going to assume it's a phone call.

Is there any way I can change this? Preferably back to two, and without rooting my phone.

Comment: You don't really say what model your device is (and you should) but it may be as simple as setting an appropriate vibration pattern in the panel for Notifications.

Comment: Kyocera Duraforce 2. I tried changing the pattern, but regardless of the pattern I choose it's always five repetitions, whereas it used to be two.